# Order points in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to make a stripplot / point plot / scatter plot, where the points in each category are sorted, based on the y value (see example in [this forum post](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1418239-how-to-color-and-label-individual-points-in-stripplot-by-category)). I would like the points in each gene category sorted (as in the linked example with the two categories: placebo and full).

How can this be done in seaborn / pandas?

A simple example input would be:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    "Gene": ["Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1",
             "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2"],
    "Value": [80, 1205, 5, 150, 50, 80,
              12, 5235, 235, 1245, 126, 10]})
```

And more elaborate:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    "Gene": ["Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1",
             "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2"],
    "Value": [80, 1205, 5, 150, 50, 80,
              12, 5235, 235, 1245, 126, 10]}),
"State": ["active", "inactive", "active", "inactive", "active", "active",
              "active", "active", "active", "inactive", "inactive", "inactive"]})
```

So the genes are the y-ticks, the values are the points and the activity is the hue.

Example of a stripplot, to illustrate the desired result:
[image: example of a stripplot]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example and the code you have implemented so far, thank you!

Comment: Something like this - but if it's easier with scatterplot or pointplot then it's fine
sns.stripplot(data = df_melt, hue = "State", x = "Gene", y = "value")

But i want the points displaced like in the linked example

Comment: Please don't hide the information in the comments. Please edit the question and add everything that is needed to understand your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on @Fourier's answer, I propose the following solution.

I don't think you can use stripplot to achieve the desired result, but that's ok, that's not what stripplot is made for anyway.
The situation is fairly straightforward if you don't have several `hues`. Then the boxplots are simply located at x-values 0,1,2... and have a `width` that can be defined in the call to boxplot (0.8 by default). Knowing these pieces of information, it is fairly simple to calculate what the x-values of our points should be so they are centered over the boxplot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Gene": ["Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1",
             "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2"],
    "Value": [80, 1205, 5, 150, 50, 80,
              12, 5235, 235, 1245, 126, 10]})

order = ['Gene1','Gene2']
width = 0.8
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(x='Gene',y='Value',data=df, orient='v', color='w', fliersize=0, order=order, width=width, ax=ax)
for x0,o in enumerate(order):
    temp_df = df[df['Gene']==o]
    x_vals = temp_df['Value'].rank(method='first')
    x_vals = np.interp(x_vals, [x_vals.min(), x_vals.max()],[x0-width/2, x0+width/2])
    ax.plot(x_vals, temp_df['Value'], 'o')
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Solution if using hue-nesting

In fact, if you are using hue-nesting, the situation is not really more complicated. It's just a matter of knowing the x-coordinates of the different box plots and their width. As it happens, [I've recently answered another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097497/how-to-put-multiple-median-values-in-the-boxplot/59105320#59105320) that had pretty much the same requirements, so both solutions are pretty close.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Gene": ["Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1",
             "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2"],
    "Value": [80, 1205, 5, 150, 50, 80,
              12, 5235, 235, 1245, 126, 10],
    "State": ["active", "inactive", "active", "inactive", "active", "active",
              "active", "active", "active", "inactive", "inactive", "inactive"]
})


order = ['Gene1','Gene2']
hue_order = ['active','inactive']
width = 0.8
# get the offsets used by boxplot when hue-nesting is used
# https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/c73055b2a9d9830c6fbbace07127c370389d04dd/seaborn/categorical.py#L367
n_levels = len(hue_order)
each_width = width / n_levels
offsets = np.linspace(0, width - each_width, n_levels)
offsets -= offsets.mean()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(x='Gene',y='Value',hue='State', data=df, orient='v', color='w', fliersize=0, order=order, hue_order=hue_order, width=width, ax=ax)

for x0,o in enumerate(order):
    for h,off in zip(hue_order, offsets):
        temp_df = df[(df['Gene']==o)&(df['State']==h)]
        x_vals = temp_df['Value'].rank(method='first')
        x_vals = np.interp(x_vals, [x_vals.min(), x_vals.max()],[(x0+off)-each_width/2, (x0+off)+each_width/2])
        ax.plot(x_vals, temp_df['Value'], 'o')
```

[image]

Comment: Very good. It is a shame that sorting within different hues not implemented in seaborn, yet. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Thanks! I would love to use it with hues, as in the elaborate example in the updated question. It doesn't seem straight forward. Any recommendations?

Comment: Note also that I included `rank(method='first')` to deal with ties in the ranking process to avoid overlapping points

Answer (score 3):

For future questions please consider this help page, which will guide you in the process of providing some data to exemplify your problem and help others to respond more precisely:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

The most generic way to this

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

#generate some random points to plot
df = pd.DataFrame({"y":np.random.randint(0,100,20)})

#plot by sorted values using stripplot
sns.stripplot(df['y'].sort_values(), df['y'])
```

Output:

[image]

You can also create a new column that contains the ranks of the y-values:

```
df['ranks'] = df['y'].rank()
```

and then plot this using:

```
sns.stripplot(df['ranks'], df['y'])
```

**EDIT**

For your data I would try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"gene":["gene{}".format(i) for i in np.arange(1,21)], "value":np.random.randint(0,100,20), "state":np.random.randint(0,2,20)})

sns.stripplot(data=df.sort_values("value"), x="gene", y="value", hue="state")
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks that is quite nice. However, I am still in doubt. I already have the x-value to indicate the category.
sns.stripplot(data = df_melt, hue = "State", x = "Gene", y = "value") 
How can i combine it with your solution?

Comment: Sadly no. I think your solution sorts the categories.  I have both states in each gene. Even if I didn't have two states, I would want the points in each gene category sorted (as in the linked example with the two categories: placebo and full)

Comment: @twoid Again without having the first n rows of your data frame it is hard to imagine the structure.

Comment: Okay, sorry. thank you for helping me. A simple example would be:
pd.DataFrame({"Gene": ["Gene1", "Gene1","Gene1","Gene1","Gene1","Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2","Gene2","Gene2","Gene2","Gene2"],
            "Value": [80,1205,5,150,50,80,12,5235,235,1245,126,10]})